# Mechanism behind energy generation

Tags: cellular-respiration, bioenergetics, energy

I recently read about methanogens and methanotrophs. One converts CO<sub>2</sub> to methane and vice versa respectively. 
I can't get exact mechanism for the methanotrophs and I know they can't be reversed because this would result, in both directions being unable to produce energy.

Any information elaborating on the mechanism responsible for the generation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Methanotrophs oxidize methane to CO2 via a series of two electron steps with methanol, formaldehyde, and formate as intermediates."  from https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-3163-2_7 (link to a book that I can't access right now).